# How to rename a file and create a download link for it PHP

Tags: php, html, file, rename

So currently I have a html form which users submit and then a file is created and given a random name using PHP, how would I grab the file the user created and rename it and then create a download link for it?

In short steps, user fills in form, clicks submit, file with random name is created (e.g 434242.txt), download link page shows up, user clicks download link, the file they created downloads to their computer as a new file name (e.g customname.txt).

I have no idea on how I go about this, so any guidance would be great!

Here's my html form;

```
<form id="msform" action="result.php" method="post">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Basic Details</li>
        <li>Server Options</li>
        <li>Final Touches</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Add some basic details...</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
        <input type="text" name="levelName" placeholder="Level Name" />
        <input type="text" name="messageOFTD" placeholder="Message of The Day" />
        <input type="text" name="port" placeholder="Server Port (Default is 25565)" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Customize your server...</h2>
        <label for="players">Max No. of Players</label>
        <input type="text" name="maxPlayers" placeholder="Maximum No. of Players" />
        <label for="select">Default Gamemode</label>
        <select value="select" name="defaultGamemode">
            <option value="SURVIVAL" name="survival">Survival</option>
            <option value="CREATIVE" name="creative">Creative</option>
            <option value="ADVENTURE" name="adventure">Adventure</option>
            <option value="SPECTATOR" name="spectator">Spectator</option>
        </select>
        <p>Force Gamemode</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="forceGamemode" />
        <p>Difficulty</p>
        <select value="select" name="difficulty">
            <option value="0">Peaceful</option>
            <option value="1">Easy</option>
            <option value="2">Normal</option>
            <option value="3">Hard</option>
        </select>
        <p>Allow Flight</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="allowFlight" />
        <p>Enable PvP</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="enablePVP" />
        <p>Enable Command Blocks</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="enableCommandBlock"  />
        <p>Spawn Animals</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="spawnAnimals"  />
        <p>Spawn NPC's</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="spawnNPC" />
        <p>Spawn Monsters</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="spawnMobs" />

        <p>Hardcore Mode</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hardcoreMode" />

        <p>Allow Nether</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="allowNether" />

        <p>Generate Structures</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="generateStructure" />
        <p>Announce Achievements</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="announceAchievements" />


        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">A few more settings</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">You're almost done!</h3>

        <p>Online Mode</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="onlineMode" />
                <p>Enable Query</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="enableQuery" />

        <p>Enable Snooper</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="enableSnooper" />

        <p>Enable RCON</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="enableRCON" />

        <p>View Distance</p>
        <input type="text" name="viewDistance" placeholder="Default is 10" />

        <p>Level Seed</p>
        <input type="text" name="levelSeed" />

        <p>Resource Pack</p>
        <input type="text" name="pack" placeholder="Place URL of Pack Here" />

        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here's my PHP file;

```
<?php

//this code below generates a random string with 3 chars.. call it using radom_string(3);

function random_string($length) {
    $key = '';
    $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
       $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
    }

    return $key;
}

$id = random_string(3);
$ext = ".properties"; //adds file extension
$generatedBy = "#Generated by Serve A Server! Visit at http://serve.minecraftserver.uk.to/";

//force values for user file
$spawnProtection = "spawn-protection=16";
$maxTickTime = "max-tick-time=60000";
$genSettings = "generator-settings=";
$playerIdleTimeout = "player-idle-timeout=0";
$opPermissionLevel = "op-permission-level=4";
$levelType = "level-type=DEFAULT";
$networkThresh = "network-compression-threshold=256";
$maxWorldSize = "max-world-size=29999984";
$serverIP = "server-ip=";
$resourcePackHash = "resource-pack-hash=";
$whitelist = "white-list=false";
$maxBuildHeight = "max-build-height=256";

//prefixes for user file
$levelName = "level-name=";
$motd = "motd=";
$port = "server-port=";
$maxPlayers = "max-players=";
$viewDistance = "view-distance=";
$levelSeed = "level-seed=";
$pack = "resource-pack=";

//wrting to the file
$myfile = fopen("temp/tmp/server" . $id  . $ext , "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
//adding generated by Serve A Server
//fwrite($myfile, $generatedBy . "\r\n");
//$txt = isset($_POST["levelName"]) ? $levelname . $_POST["levelName"] . "\n" : '';
//fwrite($myfile, $txt);
//$txt = isset($_POST["messageOFTD"]) ? $motd . $_POST["messageOFTD"] . "\n" : '';
//fwrite($myfile, $txt);
//$txt = isset($_POST["port"]) ? $port . $_POST["port"] . "\n" : '';
//fwrite($myfile, $txt);
//$txt = isset($_POST["maxPlayers"]) ? $maxPlayers . $_POST["maxPlayers"] . "\n" : '';
//fwrite($myfile, $txt);
//$txt = isset($_POST["viewDistance"]) ? $viewDistance . $_POST["viewDistance"] . "\n" : '';
//fwrite($myfile, $txt);
//$txt = isset($_POST["levelSeed"]) ? $levelSeed . $_POST["levelSeed"] . "\n" : '';
//fwrite($myfile, $txt);
//$txt = isset($_POST["pack"]) ? $pack . $_POST["pack"] . "\n" : '';
//fwrite($myfile, $txt);

//adding the values created by the user (Note: There is an IF statement for each $_POST Variable).

fwrite($myfile, $spawnProtection . "\r\n");
fwrite($myfile, $maxTickTime . "\r\n");
fwrite($myfile, $genSettings . "\r\n");

if (isset($_POST["forceGamemode"])){
        $txt = "force-gamemode=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "force-gamemode=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

if (isset($_POST["allowNether"])){
        $txt = "allow-nether=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "allow-nether=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

switch($_POST['defaultGamemode']){
case 'SURVIVAL':
    $txt = "gamemode=0" . "\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
break;
case 'CREATIVE':
    $txt = "gamemode=1" . "\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);    
break;
case 'ADVENTURE':
    $txt = "gamemode=2" . "\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);    
break;
case 'SPECTATOR':
    $txt = "gamemode=3" . "\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);  
break;
default:
    $txt = "SOMETHING WENT WRONG!" . "\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);    
}

if (isset($_POST["enableQuery"])){
        $txt = "enable-query=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "enable-query=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

fwrite($myfile, $playerIdleTimeout . "\r\n");

switch($_POST['difficulty']){
case '0':
    $txt = "difficulty=0" . "\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
break;
case '1':
    $txt = "difficulty=1" . "\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);    
break;
case '2':
    $txt = "difficulty=2" . "\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);    
break;
case '3':
    $txt = "difficulty=3" . "\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);  
break;
default:
    $txt = "SOMETHING WENT WRONG!" . "\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);    
}

if (isset($_POST["spawnMobs"])){
        $txt = "spawn-monsters=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "spawn-monsters=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

fwrite($myfile, $opPermissionLevel . "\r\n");


fwrite($myfile, $resourcePackHash . "\r\n");

if (isset($_POST["announceAchievements"])){
        $txt = "announce-player-achievements=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "announce-player-achievements=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

if (isset($_POST["enablePVP"])){
        $txt = "pvp=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "pvp=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 


if (isset($_POST["enableSnooper"])){
        $txt = "snooper-enabled=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "snooper-enabled=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

fwrite($myfile, $levelType . "\r\n");

if (isset($_POST["hardcoreMode"])){
        $txt = "hardcore=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "hardcore=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

if (isset($_POST["enableCommandBlock"])){
        $txt = "enable-command-block=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "enable-command-block=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

if (isset($_POST["maxPlayers"])){
    if($_POST["maxPlayers"] != ""){
        $txt = $maxPlayers . $_POST["maxPlayers"] . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "max-players=20" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 
}

fwrite($myfile, $networkThresh . "\r\n");

fwrite($myfile, $maxWorldSize . "\r\n");

if (isset($_POST["port"])){
    if($_POST["port"] != ""){
        $txt = $port . $_POST["port"] . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "server-port=25565" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 
}

fwrite($myfile, $serverIP . "\r\n");

if (isset($_POST["spawnNPC"])){
        $txt = "spawn-npcs=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "spawn-npcs=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

if (isset($_POST["allowFlight"])){
        $txt = "allow-flight=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "allow-flight=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

if (isset($_POST["levelName"])){
    if($_POST["levelName"] != ""){
        $txt = $levelName . $_POST["levelName"] . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "level-name=NO_NAME_GIVEN" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 
}

if (isset($_POST["viewDistance"])){
    if($_POST["viewDistance"] != ""){
        $txt = $viewDistance . $_POST["viewDistance"] . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "view-distance=10" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 
}

if (isset($_POST["pack"])){
    if($_POST["pack"] != ""){
        $txt = $pack . $_POST["pack"] . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "resource-pack=" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 
}

if (isset($_POST["spawnAnimals"])){
        $txt = "spawn-animals=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "spawn-animals=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

fwrite($myfile, $whitelist . "\r\n");

if (isset($_POST["generateStructures"])){
        $txt = "generate-structures=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "generate-structures=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

if (isset($_POST["onlineMode"])){
        $txt = "online-mode=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "online-mode=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

fwrite($myfile, $maxBuildHeight . "\r\n");

if (isset($_POST["levelSeed"])){
    if($_POST["levelSeed"] != ""){
        $txt = $levelSeed . $_POST["levelSeed"] . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "level-seed=" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 
}

if (isset($_POST["messageOFTD"])){
    if($_POST["messageOFTD"] != ""){
        $txt = $motd . $_POST["messageOFTD"] . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "motd=Server Props. file created with ServeAServer!" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 
}

if (isset($_POST["enableRCON"])){
        $txt = "enable-rcon=true" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } else {
        $txt = "enable-rcon=false" . "\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    } 

//close the operation
fclose($myfile);

//list files
$log_directory = 'temp/tmp/';

$results_array = array();

if (is_dir($log_directory))
{
        if ($handle = opendir($log_directory))
        {
                //Notice the parentheses I added:
                while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE)
                {
                        $results_array[] = $file;
                }
                closedir($handle);
        }
}

//Output findings -- Debug Purposes 
foreach($results_array as $value)
{
    echo $value . '<br />';
}


//this delets the file after all above is done..
//array_map('unlink', glob("temp/tmp/*.properties"));

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the file in your httpdocs-dir to make it downloadable.
As i see it, your file is created in a dir "temp/tmp/", which should be in your http dir.

so you can create a download-link with

```
echo '<a href="temp/tmp/server'.$id.$ext.'">download</a>';
```

at the end after fclose() in your php-file.

[edit]
If you want to force download instead of viewing the file, you need to enable mod_headers on your apache:

Log in AS ROOT:

```
# a2enmod headers
# /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Change the http.conf for your host (name and location depends on linux distribution and server config):

```
AllowOverride All
```

create a .htaccess file in your download-dir:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:txt)$">
      ForceType application/octet-stream
      Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

As you see, force the file to download instead of viewing, is a bit tricky for inexperienced users.
better just label the download link with a text like:

*(to download the file, press right mousebutton -> save link)*

you can of course just create the .htaccess in your download-dir and hope, that mod_headers is already enabled and AllowOverride is set to "All" by default.
Please note, that the .htaccess just changes .txt-files. for other extensions you need to adjust it.

Comment: Okay this works.. sort of, when I click the link it shows the file in the browser, it doesn't actually download it. Also, before I download it, how would I rename it to a certain name? Thanks!

Comment: download it with right mousebutton -> save file to, rename it with rename('temp/tmp/server'.$id.$ext, 'yourfilename.txt');

Comment: you can force the file to download instead of showing in browser, but you need to make changes to the apache configuration for that. enable mod_header specifically, and after that create a .htaccess, that alters the MIME-type of the file. btw: pls accept the answer gacefully, if it works for you:-)

Comment: I want the process to be automatic, so having a download button will do all the work. Also, the rename bit doesn't work. It says file not found when I click the download link.

Comment: well, if you rename the file, then you of course have to change the download-link. echo '<a href="yourfilename.txt">download</a>';

Comment: Hey, so I managed to get the renaming bit to work, would it be possible for you to help me on the .htaccess to force download the file instead of viewing it? Thanks!

Comment: sure, would it be possible for you to accept the answer? ^^

Comment: try the easy way, if the above does not work: echo '<a href="yourfilename.txt" download>download</a>';

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to get it working using the .htaccess file! :) Thanks again!